# Button is not enabling again in angular form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I am new to angularjs and  using angular form , every field is require in form. After fill all the fields i want to enable submit button but it is not enabling, i tried a lot of solutions but not getting any thing. Have a look of  my HTML

```html
<form class="form" method="post" action="" name="signupForm"
   novalidate autocomplete="off" ng-controller="SignupController">
   <div class="header header-primary text-center">
      <h4>Sign Up</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="input-group">
               <span class="input-group-addon">
               <i class="material-icons">face</i>
               </span>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Person Name" name="username"
                  ng-model="user.personName" required  />
               <div class="field-message" ng-messages="signupForm.username.$error" ng-if='signupForm.username.$dirty' ng-cloak>
                  <div ng-message="required">Username is required</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
               <span class="input-group-addon">
               <i class="material-icons">email</i>
               </span>
               <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" 
                  ng-model="user.email" required />
               <div class="field-message" ng-messages="signupForm.email.$error" ng-if='signupForm.email.$dirty' ng-cloak>
                  <div ng-message="required">Email is required</div>
                  <div ng-message="email">Must be a valid email</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
               <span class="input-group-addon">
               <i class="material-icons">lock_outline</i>
               </span>
               <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" 
                  ng-model="user.password" ng-minlength="6"  required />
               <div class="field-message" ng-messages="signupForm.password.$error" ng-if='signupForm.password.$dirty' ng-cloak>
                  <div ng-message="required">Password is required</div>
                  <div ng-message="minlength">Password must have minimum 6 characters</div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group" id="locationField">
               <span class="input-group-addon">
               <i class="material-icons">place</i>
               </span>
               <input type="text" id="autocomplete" class="form-control" name="location" 
                  placeholder="Location" ng-model="user.place" onFocus="geolocate()" required="required" />
               <div class="field-message" ng-messages="signupForm.location.$error" ng-if='signupForm.location.$dirty' ng-cloak>
                  <div ng-message="required">location is required</div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="material-icons">reorder</i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="streetAddr2"
               placeholder="Street Address 2" id="route" ng-model="user.streetAddr2" required="required" disabled="disabled" />
            <div class="field-message" ng-messages="signupForm.streetAddr2.$error" ng-if='signupForm.streetAddr2.$dirty' ng-cloak>
               <div ng-message="required">Street Address is required</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="material-icons">reorder</i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city"
               placeholder="City" id="locality" ng-model="user.city" required="required" disabled="disabled" />
            <div class="field-message" ng-messages="signupForm.city.$error" ng-if='signupForm.city.$dirty' ng-cloak>
               <div ng-message="required">City is required</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="material-icons">reorder</i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state"
               placeholder="State" id="administrative_area_level_1"  ng-model="user.state"  required="required" disabled="disabled" />
            <div class="field-message" ng-messages="signupForm.state.$error" ng-if='signupForm.state.$dirty' ng-cloak>
               <div ng-message="required">State is required</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="material-icons">reorder</i>
            </span>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="zip"
               placeholder="Zip Code" id="postal_code" ng-model="user.zip"  
               required="user.required" disabled="disabled" ng-minlength="6"  ng-maxlength="8" />
            <div class="field-message" ng-messages="signupForm.zip.$error" ng-if='signupForm.zip.$dirty' ng-cloak>
               <div ng-message="minlength">Zip Code must have minimum 6 digits</div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="material-icons">reorder</i>
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country"
               placeholder="Country" id="country" ng-model="user.country"  required="user.required" disabled="disabled" />
            <div class="field-message" ng-messages="signupForm.country.$error" ng-if='signupForm.country.$dirty' ng-cloak>
               <div ng-message="required">Country Name is required</div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="footer text-center">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-simple btn-primary btn-lg"
         ng-click="signup($event)"  ng-disabled="signupForm.$invalid" />Signup
   </div>
</form>
```

Please help me .

Comment: When you fill all fields you can check what is wrong to review html in dev tools,  if input is wrong it will has class like 'ng-invalid'.

Comment: Provided snippet isn't valid, showing console errors. Mb You get some errors in console when fill the form?

Comment: onFocus="geolocate()" is throwing exception. please provide js files as well.

Comment: first remove `disabled="disabled` from last few fields since all fields are required. Check http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/9235/

Comment: @Razzka , it's not showing any console error.

Comment: @HarshalSawant is used disabled="disabled for few fields because i want to disable them at the form loading, as user fill location they will be enable.

Comment: @elpofigisto all inputs is right i check many time in console.

Comment: @SarunUK not getting either exception or error .

Comment: I would have used `ngDisabled` in place of `disabled="disabled`. Explain in brief what's the issue exactly are you facing.

Comment: @HarshalSawant I have form  all fields in form all require , and button will be disable , as user fill all files submit button will be enable , but after filled all the fields submit button is still disable, no exception and error is showing , and all the input is correct. And i replaced all the disabled="disabled with   ""ngDisabled" and its working fine. i used it because fields having ngDisabled they will be disable initially and i used ngAutocomplete  with them, as user will fill location using place  api , they will autocomplete.

Comment: I debug the code and find  having problem with Zipcode,  Expected  to be a number. The input[number] and input[range] directives require the model to be a number. this field is auto filled using google place api.

Comment: if i use <input type="text" > instead of number and remove ng-minlength="6"  ng-maxlength="8" , and ng-disabled="signupForm.$invalid" from the buttom it works perfectly. i can use  <input type="text" > but button should be disable until all field must be fill.